# Make PhpStorm recognize react props

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

In my current PhpStorm setup, some react property fields are marked as unresolved while others aren't:

[image: PhpStorm Screenshot of the problem]

I find this very confusing because it implies to me that my `props.value` is OK while my `props.onClick` isn't. When I <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> on `props.value` I am lead to some unrelated code.

Because I currently do not define the property fields anywhere (I don't use TypeScript), I understand that it would be difficult for the IDE to recognize "the correct" property fields. However I would like to at least disable any kind of validation for property fields and omit the misleading suggestion that some fields are OK and others aren't.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want to use TypeScript or propTypes then I would recommend installing and integrating flow in your project. It does generally do a good job at inferring types on its own and you will be able to also declare types if you need to, but even if you don't declare types it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props resolving/completion is only supported for components with explicit `propTypes` declaration (see [WEB-31785](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31785)).
As exact match can't be found, the IDE tries to match the property by name only, thus resolving it to some unrelated stuff:(

Comment: ok thanks. I might think about using typescript or including flow.